# Is there any way to extract a value and its index from a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to extract values from a matrix with their index

For example:

My input is

```
S = [[1, 2], [4, 8]]
```

My output should be

```
{1: (1, 1), 2: (1, 2), 4: (2, 1), 8: (2, 2)}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```py
result = {c: (x, y) for y, r in enumerate(S) for x, c in enumerate(r)}
```

Output:

```py
{1: (0, 0), 2: (1, 0), 4: (0, 1), 8: (1, 1)}
```

---

Note: in Python indexes start from 0, not from 1. If you want to start from 1, use:

```py
result = {c: (x, y) for y, r in enumerate(S, 1) for x, c in enumerate(r, 1)}
```

Output:

```py
{1: (1, 1), 2: (2, 1), 4: (1, 2), 8: (2, 2)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, if there can be duplicates ?

Comment: @Sami - then use the second piece of code from [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857660/18746959)

Answer (score 0):

Python numbers its indexes from 0, not from one.  You seem to be looking for something like this:

```
result = {}
for y,row in enumerate(S):
    for x,col in enumerate(row):
        result[col] = (x,y)
```

If there can be duplicates, this gets a little more complicated:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for y,row in enumerate(S):
    for x,col in enumerate(row):
        result[col].append( (x,y) )
```